# pheatmap with larger gap_col in R

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

In R function `pheatmap::pheatmap`, is it possible to adjust the gap distances?

---

In the following example, I created a gap in columns 3 and 4 using parameter `gaps_col=3`. Yet, the gap is too small visually. I wonder if there is a way to adjust the gap size? At this moment, I do not consider using other packages.

```
# Create test matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# Draw heatmaps
pheatmap(test, cluster_cols = F, gaps_col = 3) # creating gap using gaps_col.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by saying multiple times the same `gaps_col` for example three times column 3 as a vector like this:

```r
library(pheatmap)
# Create test matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# Draw heatmaps
pheatmap(test, cluster_cols = F, gaps_col = c(3, 3, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

6 times:

```r
# Draw heatmaps
pheatmap(test, cluster_cols = F, gaps_col = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>